# If URL contains string "string A" or "string B" or "string C" do this

Tags: jquery

I don't know how to phrase my question, so here's more of an explanation... Problem I need to solve: Only display this script on pages A, B and C. They are wordpress pages so I can't just paste the script into each page. I wrote this script:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("url-string-a") > -1){
    jQuery( "form" ).addClass( "active" );
}
```

but I don't know how to apply it to more than one URL without copy and pasting this 3 times. (In my actual scenario, this script needs to run on 10 pages, so I don't want to copy and paste this 10 times. I'm sure there's a cleaner way of doing this.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you think about copy-paste, instead think about functions that should wrap the code you were going to repeat again and again. One possible approach:

```
function containsAny(haystack, needles) {
  return needles.some(function(str) {
    return haystack.indexOf(str) > -1;
  });
}
```

Here you created a function that takes two arguments: `haystack` (a string) and `needles` (an array of strings), the former will be checked for any of the latter.

Then just use this function inside `if` check:

```
if (containsAny(location.href, ['url-string-a', 'url-string-b', ...])) {
  $('form').addClass('pnt');
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: containsAny is not defined"

Comment: I think the use of `some` is a key part of this solution that many would not already be familiar with.

Comment: @nthChild - Have you defined the function in that script?

Comment: @nthChild Where's the function declaration placed? It should be in scope of the code using it.

Comment: Ok I got it mostly working except it says "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" for the line where the .addClass occurs